# UTF-8 Character error in R

Tags: r, list, recursion, utf-8

Basically, I am trying create a list of multiple .txt files from different folder and subfolder in R. I have a perfect loop that achieves this- Here's the problem: it keeps getting an error saying

> Error in readChar(textfiles[k], file.info(textfiles[k])$size) : 
>     invalid UTF-8 input in readChar()

I've come to understand this as basically, there are some characters that are not part of the UTF-8 character list (which I'm assuming would be characters like e's with accent and such). So I went through the files and tried to delete any that I thought weren't UTF-8 and the error still happens.

Here is my code for reference:

```
library(tm)

# lists the file paths of the different groups of companies
sectors<-list.dirs(path="/Users/MyName/Desktop/PROJ",full.names=T,recursive=F)
# lists the names of the different groups of companies
sectornames<-list.dirs(path="/Users/MyName/Desktop/PROJ",full.names=F,recursive=F) 
#makes an empty list
corpora.list<-vector("list", length(sectornames))
names(corpora.list)<-sectornames
#loops through each file within each company within each group and adds them to a nested list
for (i in 1:length(sectors)){
corpora.list[i]<-list(temp=list.dirs(path=sectors[i],full.names=T,recursive=F))
names(corpora.list[[i]])<-list.dirs(path=sectors[i],full.names=F,recursive=F)
for(j in 1:length(corpora.list[[i]])) {
textfiles<-list.files(as.character(corpora.list[[i]][j]),full.names=T)
for (k in 1:length(textfiles)) {
  textfiles[k]<-readChar(textfiles[k],file.info(textfiles[k])$size)
}
corpora.list[[i]][j]<-list(temp=textfiles)
#corpora.list[[i]][j]<-paste(textfiles,collapse="")     #### if you want content from all page files in one string, not sure it's necessary after all though ###
 }
}
```